# JavaScript function in Internet Explorer 11 not running

Tags: javascript, html

I built this crude page for my work to help generate config files. It works wonderfully in Chrome and Firefox, but will not function in IE. When you press the generate button it doesn't do anything.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with it?

```js
function myFunction() {

  var name = document.getElementById("input_name").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("input_phone").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("input_address").value;
  var ip = document.getElementById("input_ip").value;
  var mask = document.getElementById("input_mask").value;
  var gate = document.getElementById("input_gate").value;
  var enable = document.getElementById("input_enable").value;
  var login = document.getElementById("input_login").value;
  var vlan = document.getElementById("input_vlan").value;
  var digits = document.getElementById("input_digits").value;
  var analog = document.getElementById("analog");
  var pri = document.getElementById("pri");
  var extended = document.getElementById("extended");

  if (analog.checked) {
    var str = `...config file stuff...`;
    var res = str.replace(/example_name/g, name).replace(/example_phone/g, phone).replace(/example_address/g, address).replace(/example_ip/g, ip).replace(/example_gateway/g, gate).replace(/example_mask/g, mask).replace(/example_enable/g, enable).replace(/example_login/g, login);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
  } else if (pri.checked) {
    var str = `...config file stuff...`;
    var res = str.replace(/example_name/g, name).replace(/example_phone/g, phone).replace(/example_address/g, address).replace(/example_ip/g, ip).replace(/example_gateway/g, gate).replace(/example_mask/g, mask).replace(/example_enable/g, enable).replace(/example_login/g, login).replace(/example_digits/g, digits);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
  } else {
    var str = `...config file stuff...`;
    var res = str.replace(/example_name/g, name).replace(/example_phone/g, phone).replace(/example_address/g, address).replace(/example_ip/g, ip).replace(/example_gateway/g, gate).replace(/example_mask/g, mask).replace(/example_enable/g, enable).replace(/example_login/g, login).replace(/example_vlan/g, vlan);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: Gainsboro;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.header {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: PaleGreen;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container input[type="text"] {
  width: 95%;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p><b>Enter the information and click the button to generate a config file.</b></p>
    <p>Customer Name:
      <input name="input_name" type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_name" class="searchField" align="left" />
    </p>
    <p>Customer Phone #:
      <input name="input_phone" type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_phone" class="searchField" align="left" />
    </p>
    <p>Address:
      <input name="input_address" type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_address" class="searchField" align="left" />
    </p>
    <p>IP Address:
      <input name="input_ip" type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_ip" class="searchField" />
    </p>
    <p>Subnet Mask:
      <input name="input_mask" type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_mask" class="searchField" />
    </p>
    <p>Gateway:
      <input name="input_gate" type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_gate" class="searchField" />
    </p>
    <p>Enable Password:
      <input name="input_enable" type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_enable" class="searchField" />
    </p>
    <p>Login Password:
      <input name="input_login" type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_login" class="searchField" />
    </p>
    <p>Extended Reach VLAN:
      <input name="input_login" type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_vlan" class="searchField" />
    </p>
    <p>Digits Transferred: (Choose 0, 3, 4, 7, or all)
      <input name="input_login" type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_digits" class="searchField" />
    </p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" style="width:120px">Generate</button>
    <input type="radio" name="config-type" id="analog" checked>
    <label for="analog">Analog Only</label>
    <input type="radio" id="pri" name="config-type">
    <label for="pri">Analog and PRI</label>
    <input type="radio" id="extended" name="config-type">
    <label for="extended">Extended Reach PRI</label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <p id="demo">Config will generate here:</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are using all ES6 ones... I don't think it is supported yet.

Comment: saying "I'm sorry it's messy" won't magically make our eyes better at sifting through your code. Format it properly and reduce it to the relevant parts *only*

Comment: I apologize, I am not very knowledgeable quite yet. How would I be able to make this compatible with IE in that case?

Comment: I've formatted your code. In future, please consider adding your code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code snippet (by clicking the code icon when writing your question). Don't forget to click the `Tidy` button as well. Not only will this help people read your code, but your code will be executable from within your question itself, saving others time. This means they'll be more willing to help, and able to help you faster. For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: My guess to your problem is that you're using backticks (`) instead of either single or double quotes in your strings: `...config file stuff...`. This is likely parsing correctly on Chrome and Firefox because they can work out what you **meant**, though IE is likely more stringent. Try replacing these with single or double quotes, and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I apologize for all my noob mistakes, I'm just trying to figure things out here and need a little help. I believe @PraveenKumar has the right answer here regarding the backticks. Unfortunately, I have hundreds of lines in these config files. Is there a better way to add large amounts of text as a string?

Comment: You can use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) if you want to support old browsers and use es6 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The backticks used in my strings are indeed ES6 and incompatible with Internet Explorer.

I will use the Internet Explorer compatible syntax:

```
var str = "\nexample\nexample\n";
```